# How to up handle an uncle directory in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

How can I call within my Makefile a grand-uncle directory?

I have

```
LIBDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/lib
SRCDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/src
```

and my Makefile is in `$(ROOTDIR)/src/utils`.

I figured out how to go up one directory with

```
DIRUP := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))/..))
```

but I couldn't make it further!

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want call `make -C $(ROOTDIR)`?

Comment: Dear uzsolt, I run a Makefile from `src` that launches `make` on Makefiles in subdirectories of `src` (including `utils`) and I have a `.a` archive in `lib`, which is a brother directory of `src`. This archive is updated in `utils/Makefile`  and linked to in a Makefile of another subdirectory of `src`. My question relates to `utils/Makefile`, but perhaps a better `src/Makefile` could help (by referring `lib` from `src/Makefile`).

Comment: How about `../../utils`?

Comment: ...Or `$(abspath $(PWD)/../../utils)`?

Comment: Perfect, Beta, many thanks! But since the Makefile is called from another Makefile one directory above I changed to

Comment: ... CURRENTDIR := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
LIBDIR := $(abspath $(CURRENTDIR)/../../lib)